# Copying string to another string in C++ and printing its characters?

Tags: c++, string, copy

I have a small program, where I have declared two string variables. I convert the first letter of the entered string to a capital one and than I copy the content of the first string to the second. However, if I try to print its contents (of the m string), the program prints nothing. Can you tell me why that happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

string n, m;

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    char first_letter = n.at(0);
    char f = toupper(first_letter);
    n[0] = f;
    for(int s = 0; s < n.length(); s++) {
        m[s] = n.at(s);
    }
    for(int p = 0; p < m.length(); p++) {
        cout << m[p] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'm' string length is 0 since you have never resized it to the length of string 'n'

Comment: You really should have used the `at()` function on `m`.  You would have instantly seen the error.  `m.at(s) = n.at(s);`

Comment: To copy `n` to `m` you just have to do `m = n;`

Answer (score 3):

Why so complicated?
I assume you are using `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string n,m;
int main(){
    std::cin>>n;
    n[0] = std::toupper(n.at(0));
    m = n;
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

The `at()` function performs a runtime check, if the index is out of bounds or not. The `operator[]` doesn't.

Comment: Psst, you need to put `std::` before `cin` (you did put it for `cout`). Sadly, I can't edit answers yet, so I can't add it for you.

Comment: @TheAspiringHacker Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing is printed is that your `m`-string has the length zero. In the first loop you are basically writing to unallocated memory and not appending the new values to the end of `m`.

Answer (score 0):

The string "m" is built using the default constructor of std::string

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

> Default constructor. Constructs empty string (zero size and unspecified capacity).

The second loop is not processed by your program ( because m.length()=0 )